# extract value from hidden input using xpath and input.io

Tags: import.io

I want to extract a list of dates from a hidden input, but I really don't understand what I'm doing.  On the web page there's code similar to:

I'm trying the xpath:

//input[@id="dates_list"]/@value

But that leaves my HTML column empty in import.io.  (At least I have a blue underline on my xpath, instead of red, so I think I have the syntax correct.)

Comment: can you add an example or sample of the code , also if you use this xpath to select a value , then you should change your column type to text to see the selection cause you are targeting whats inside value not the html tag so an html column won't display that

Comment: The code I'm trying to extract from is:

<input type="hidden" id="dates_list" value="10/23/2015,10/24/2015,10/25/2015,10/26/2015" />

Comment: Now that I try it, it works.  I thought I had to have the column as HTML, since I wasn't trying to extract from any text on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code

```
//input[@id="dates_list"]/@value
```

is not targeting your example , it should be like this

```
//input[@id="showtime_dates_list"]/@value
```

also in this case the column type Should be Text , if you need the html you should make it like this

```
//input[@id="showtime_dates_list"]
```